# Access a variable from different class

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to access a variable from a sibling of initiator of current class, as you can see a prototype example, which does not work:

```
class webConfig {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->settings = new settings();
    $this->conf = new conf();
    $this->info = new info();
  }
}

class settings {
  public function setInfo() {

    return parent::conf->info;

  }
}

class conf {
  public function __construct() {

    $this->info = "10";

  }
}
```

Is there any way I can access the **info** variable from **conf** class in the settings->setInfo() function?

Comment: Classes need to `extend` others to be able to access their internals. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I already do have extend in my original code, but it is used for something else. I have a class which contains subscriptions expiry dates, and another class which checks if the subscription is active, but to check that, it will need access to the other class with subscription dates.

Comment: The code is "too" messy. anyway, you should `extend` you classes to inherit from their parents. `class Setting extends Config {...}` then you would have `$this->info` at your disposal if you have called `Config`'s constructor, eg. in your `Settings` class have `public function __construct() { parent::__constructor(); ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your code examples, what you are going to achieve, but here are the general steps to solve problems in PHP OOP.

1. Variables declared under class are called properties (or fields).
2. Declare them and make them private or protected. More information on that can be found in PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php
3. Add getters and setters for your properties (`getProperty()`/`setProperty($value)`).
4. Use PHP OOP inheritance. More details can be found in PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php